# button_to in Rails 4 : Redirection to Controller action with params and Bootstrap Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails 4 project, in a Customer view I want to define a **button_to** , to call the **my_method** in my customer controller. Also I want to pass some params also with bootstarp class: **class: "btn btn-primary"**.

I tried this :

```
<td><%= button_to "Charge Customer",charge_lease_customer_customers_path, params: { doc_delete: true }, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
```

**In my routes.rb**

```
get 'charge_lease_customer' => 'customers#charge_lease_customer', as: :charge_lease_customer
```

When I click on the button the following error screen appears:

```
No route matches [POST] "/customers/charge_lease_customer"
```

How to achive it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= button_to "Charge Customer", charge_lease_customer_customers_path, method: :get, params: { doc_delete: true }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

As per the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

> If no `:method` modifier is given, it will default to performing a `POST` operation

--

Since your route is a `GET` request, the Rails does not recognize what you're trying to write. Your `button_to` helper is populating the route with a `POST` verb. You need to explicitly define `method: :get` in order to make the routing valid

---

You should also look at your `routes`, specifically that, wherever possible, you should be scoping your routes around your [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :customers do 
   get :charge_lease_customer, on: :collection
end
```

---

**Update**

You shouldn't be passing pre-defined data through your routes *unless* the data is openly changeable. IE maybe you wanted to set `doc_delete` or whatever.

If you want to edit a particular `customer`, you'll want a [*member* route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :companies do
   get :charge_lease_customer, on: :member #-> url.com/customers/:id/charge_lease_customer
end
```

The value of this is that it allows you to pass the `:id` param, which can be picked up by your controller:

```
#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def charge_lease_customer
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id] 
      # do something with @customer
   end 
end
```

--

If you wanted to pass customer-specific data through your params, you'll have to make sure it's all on a "top level" param structure:

```
<%= button_to "x", button_path, params: { customer_id: @customer.id, customer_name: @customer_name } %>
```

This is not recommended - too much [configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

Comment: Pech : Thank you Rich for the correction, is it possible to pass a collection obeject "@customer" which contains the customer details with this button params ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? "contains the customer details" - what do you mean?

Comment: "@Customer" contains the f_name, l_name, user_id etc

Comment: and why do you need to pass that data to the controller?

Comment: In the charge_lease_customer method I need the customer details to perform some action with the customer details, thats why, and how to hide the params passed along with the link?

Comment: hmm. I think your pattern is wrong (you shouldn't be passing all that info through a link). I'll update the response for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101456/discussion-between-praveen-george-and-rich-peck).